# gem install rails -v '4.2.4' failed to compile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/nagaraju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@maxmywealth/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/ext/nokogiri
/home/nagaraju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160226-5567-umlwr8.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/nagaraju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
/home/nagaraju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /home/nagaraju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `block in try_compile'
    from /home/nagaraju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:522:in `with_werror'
    from /home/nagaraju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:571:in `try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:80:in `nokogiri_try_compile'
    from extconf.rb:87:in `block in add_cflags'
    from /home/nagaraju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/mkmf.rb:619:in `with_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:86:in `add_cflags'
    from extconf.rb:336:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/nagaraju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@maxmywealth/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/nagaraju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@maxmywealth/gems/nokogiri-1.6.7.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/nagaraju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4@maxmywealth/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.7.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: If you read through the error messages carefully, you'll know exactly what to do. Hint: "You have to install development tools first."

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you have to install developer tools first. Which is a simple command in the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

After the installation is complete. Try installing `rails`.

Let us know, otherwise.